# MDX: sum over time with range in rows

Tags: sum, mdx, average, rows

I have a day level in my time dimension.

I want to output the sum/avg for a selected range of days like in the following statement:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.[sum1] AS 
    Sum([Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk]) 
  MEMBER measures.[sum2] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [D_Datum].[Datum].[Tag]
     ,[Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[stock]
   ,[Measures].[sum1]
   ,[Measures].[sum2]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      {[D_item].[itemno].[itemno].MEMBERS}
     ,{
        [D_Date].[Date].[day].[30.01.2017] : [D_Date].[Date].[Day].[05.02.2017]
      }
    ) ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

My goal is to show the sum/avg along the date-dimension filtered on rows.[image]

Instead of 40/1653 i want sum to display 250 for the sum or 35,7 for the average. (1653 is obviously the sum of the entire day level). I want to add this calculated member to an Excel-Sheet. Thus the time range set is variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum/avg rows across the specific range you can do something like this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.[sum1] AS 
    Sum([Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk]) 
  MEMBER measures.[sum2] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [D_Datum].[Datum].[Tag]
     ,[Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk]
    ) 
  MEMBER [D_Date].[Date].[All].[DaySum] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [D_Date].[Date].[day].[30.01.2017] : [D_Date].[Date].[Day].[05.02.2017]
    ) 
  MEMBER [D_Date].[Date].[All].[DayAvg] AS 
    Avg
    (
      [D_Date].[Date].[day].[30.01.2017] : [D_Date].[Date].[Day].[05.02.2017]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[stock]
   ,[Measures].[sum1]
   ,[Measures].[sum2]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      {[D_item].[itemno].[itemno].MEMBERS}
     ,{
        {
          [D_Date].[Date].[day].[30.01.2017] : [D_Date].[Date].[Day].[05.02.2017]
        }
       ,[D_Date].[Date].[All].[DaySum]
       ,[D_Date].[Date].[All].[DayAvg]
      }
    ) ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I think this won't work since the interval would be fixed and  thus by changing the Excel-Filter not being passed on to the result?

Comment: @rasenkantenstein Correct - to make this dynamic I'm unsure. Although a workaround would be to add custom measures for RollingSum and RollingAvg - rather than the approach you're currently taking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Axis function to define the current set on your axis:

```
WITH 
MEMBER measures.[sum] AS 
Sum(
    Axis(1),
    [Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk]
) 
MEMBER measures.[avg] AS 
AVG(
    Axis(1),
    [Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk]
) 

SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Menge_Artikel_Stk],[Measures].[sum],[Measures].[avg]} ON 0,
  NON EMPTY {[D_Date].[Date].[day].[30.01.2017]:[D_Date].[Date].[Day].[05.02.2017]} ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```